# How to force Manipulate to use preserve control settings over successive evaluations

Tags: front-end, manipulate

I have this Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {a, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Sin[a x]]

Now, I realize I had mistyped the expression and it's actually `x^2` instead. I go back and fix it, but when I evaluate the cell again, the value of `a` reverts to default/zero.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried multiple things from various Q&A: adding `SaveDefinitions -> True`, saving parameter to a global variable within the `Manipulate` block, using bookmarks, but none of them achieved the effect of having the `Manipulate` start up with a previously-set control value.

Interesting, I find that saving the parameter to a global variable, and then initialize the parameter with the same global variable solves the problem, i.e., `Manipulate` can remember the manipulated parameter from a previous run. If I add the option `SaveDefinitions -> True`, the value is also saved between sessions.

Below is an example: `a` remains at the same value even when the expression in `Manipulate` was changed and the cell was evaluated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I went to the chat room to ask people if doing this is OK. I was told that I should not do this. What kind of potential issues would I have with this method? And if it's bad, is there another method to achieve the same result, i.e., preventing `Manipulate` from resetting control values after each evaluation?

Comment: @seismatica For a simple `Manipulate` like this one I find your approach rather clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a lokal variable?

Define a local variable first, then do your plot:

```
In[1]:= startingA = 0;

In[2]:= Manipulate[
           startingA = a;
           Plot[Sin[a x^2], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
           , {{a, startingA}, 0, 3}]
```

(Note: The vaiable has NOT to be in the same evaluation cell as Manipulate[]!)

The first time a starts at the defined value zero (it could be any number inside the given range).

[image]

Change a:

[image]

Now you can change the function in the Plot and eveluate Manipulate[] again. a start at your last a/startingA:

```
Manipulate[
 startingA = a;
 Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
 , {{a, startingA}, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Animated GIF with the complete process:
[image]

Giving the Range in Manipulate as

```
{{a, startingA}, 0, 3}
```

says Manipulate should change the value "a" in the range between 0 and 3 with the starting value "startingA".
One could give the range also as

```
{{a, startingA}, 0, 3, 1}
```

In this case "1" defines the stepsize.

Comment: Could you help me understand what {{a,startingA},0,2} is supposed to me? Is this the same thing as initializing a with startingA. I've never seen a range written like this before.

Comment: @seismatica It says Manipulate[] to change a between 0 and 2 starting at startingA. With initializing it first to zero, to first startpoint for a is zero. With startingA=a; in Manipulate[] you're saving your current a to startingA in every step. (And startingA is stored outside Manipulate[].) So next time you evaluate Manipulate[] again, startingA has still the "old value of a" and will start at this point with changing a.   ... I may should edit this in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and effort to clarify your answer. This fix is working well for me. BTW how did you make that gif?

Comment: @seismatica Making animated GIFs is easy using LICEcap ([link](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)).

Comment: you rock! ugh 15 char!

Comment: [a gif for you](http://i.imgur.com/URivaXC.gif)